# android change background of activity

Tags: android, background, drawable

I am trying to use the following to change the background to an image stored on the sd card:

```
    String pathName = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ "/newbackground.jpg";
    Resources res = getResources();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
    BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.fred);
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
```

But it keeps crashing.

I´m using setBackgroundDrawable as I want it to work below api 16 and it is deprecated.

I put in a check to see if pathname exists and it does.

Any ideas?

mark

Comment: which line causes the crash?

Comment: try adding LogCat error log

Comment: view.setBackgroundDrawable(bd); causes the error